# get data from php server before document load

Tags: javascript

in order to recover data from server I use XMLHttpRequest and my code is this (it works fine)

```
window.onload = function getArtists() {
    xmlhttpLoad=new XMLHttpRequest();           
    xmlhttpLoad.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttpLoad.readyState==4 && xmlhttpLoad.status==200) {
            // put data in an invisible HTML elem           
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to use a particular library, but it requires that this data are loaded BEFORE document document.onload is fired. How can I do this? Can I use the code above but block HTML parsing until data are loaded? I mean something like

```
<head>
    <script>
        // block parsing until data are loaded
        // put data from server in a variable
    </script>
    <script src="newLib.js"></script>
<head>
```

Comment: Can you just hide all html in the body (`display: none`) call ajax then show them again after successfully request?

Comment: the problem is that library does some stuff with that data when window.onload event is fired, so this shouldn't work

Comment: Sounds like a crazy library if it won't work without this constraint and the docs don't tell you how to achieve this. What is the library?

Comment: @Brad You right but I modified the library to be used in a quite different way than its original purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use the `load` event but just run the code directly, it will start immediately when the script block has been parsed.

To make the parsing of the next block wait for the AJAX response, you have to make a synchronous request. You do that by supplying `false` for the third parameter (async) in the `open` call:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  xmlhttpLoad=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttpLoad.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttpLoad.readyState==4 && xmlhttpLoad.status==200) {
        // put data in an invisible HTML elem           
    }
  }
  xmlhttpLoad.open("get", "somepage", false);

  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="newLib.js"></script>
<head>
```

}

Comment: @LorenzoC I have to say its what I've answered to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to set your AJAX call to be `async = false`, so it will stop the page execution until it finishes.

Answer (score 1):

You could load the library when the data is ready:

```
xmlhttpLoad=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttpLoad.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttpLoad.readyState==4 && xmlhttpLoad.status==200) {
        // put data in an invisible HTML elem
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "newLib.js";
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    }
}
xmlhttpLoad.open("get", "somepage", false);
```

Comment: I thought it was just dependent on the data

Comment: In this case you can set a onload event for the script being added: `script.onload = function() { // code here for when library is have loaded }`